# Update issue status using Jira GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, jira

There seem to be little to no documentation on how to use the Atlassian GraphQL API, so I've so far tried my best with just figuring it out from the schema.

However, I have no idea on how to perform the mutations. My goal is to change the current status of an issue (e.g. from "In Progress" to "Review") using GraphQL.

I've found a `updateSingleSelectField` which might be able to do what I'm hoping for, but it's unclear how it works (which ids should be used for the input, and how to indicate which value it should be updated to).

```
mutation UpdateSingleSelectField($input: JiraUpdateSingleSelectFieldInput!) {
  jira {
    updateSingleSelectField(input: $input) @optIn(to: "JiraIssueFieldMutations") {
      field {
        fieldId
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the only documentation I've seen so far:
https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/atlassian-graphql-api/graphql